# Генерация кодов (строки)

Tags: php

Поставлена задача генерировать коды для активации,
которые потом будут отправляться клиенту в составе урла.
Думаю, тривиальная задача.
Но возник спор с коллегами, как сделать лучше.

- Хардкодом: сделать массив английского алфавита в верхнем и нижнем регистре и рандомом получать разные значения;
- Рандомом: генерировать цифры в нужном диапазоне аски и передавать их в `chr()`.

Интересуют преимущества и недостатки каждого метода.

Comment: `strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(1, time()), 1)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем вам не нравится **uniqid()** или, если вы используете MySQL, **UUID()**?

Comment: Думаю сойдёт. Спасибо

Comment: Эти функции не генерируют достаточно случайных значений - их цель другая. В сгенерированных идентификаторах будет зашиты сведения о машине, где они были получены.